# Развёртывать штаб или разворачивать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, значение-слов

Заспорили мы с супругой о том, как правильно выразить процесс размещения штаба, войск.
Я говорю, что уместно употребить слова "развёртывание", "развёртывать". А она считает, что можно "разворачивать".
*Где будем разворачивать штаб?* (Не развёртывать, а разворачивать.)
Порывшись в сети, нашёл разное, в том числе и то, что оба эти слова можно употребить, — суть не изменится. Я в сомнении. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

В военной академии учили, что разворачивается селедка и колбаса из газеты, силы и подразделения на местности развертываются